# Same program is 10 times slower on windows

Tags: c

I wrote a simple c program that copies 10 million bytes from a file and pastes them in reverse order on another file (this is done one byte at a time, I know it's not efficient but it's just to make some tests), I don't understand why on linux it takes 2.5 seconds while on windows it takes more than 20 seconds. I run the same program changing only the paths.
I use windows 10 and archlinux, the files are on an ntfs partition.

code on windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void get_nth_byte(FILE *fp, int nth_index,unsigned char* output){
    fseek(fp,nth_index,SEEK_SET);
    fread(output, sizeof(unsigned char), 1,fp);
}

int main() {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    //
    FILE* input = fopen( "C:\\Users\\piero\\Desktop\\input.txt","rb");
    FILE* output = fopen("C:\\Users\\piero\\Desktop\\output.txt","wb");
    unsigned char byte;
    for (int i = 10000000; i > 0; i--) {
        get_nth_byte(input,i,&byte);
        fwrite(&byte, sizeof(unsigned char),1,output);
    }
    //
    clock_t end = clock();
    double result = (double) (end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f",result);
    return 0;
}
```

code on linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void get_nth_byte(FILE *fp, int nth_index,unsigned char* output){
    fseek(fp,nth_index,SEEK_SET);
    fread(output, sizeof(unsigned char), 1,fp);
}

int main() {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    //
    FILE* input = fopen( "/run/media/piero/Windows/Users/piero/Desktop/input.txt","rb");
    FILE* output = fopen("/run/media/piero/Windows/Users/piero/Desktop/output.txt","wb");
    unsigned char byte;
    for (int i = 10000000; i > 0; i--) {
        get_nth_byte(input,i,&byte);
        fwrite(&byte, sizeof(unsigned char),1,output);
    }
    //
    clock_t end = clock();
    double result = (double) (end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f",result);
    return 0;
}
```

output on linux : 2.224549

output on windows : 25.349647

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem by using cygwin rather than mingwin, now it takes about 4.3 seconds

Comment: How did you compile the program on both systems? Did you remember to enable optimizations for both?

Comment: I guess you are not really using the filename "path" for both files since you wrote that you are writing to another file. So maybe edit the code to make it clear that the files are different.

Comment: both run on the same machine? Not running windows in a VM right?

Comment: Do both machines have the same kind of hard drive?

Comment: @BillLynch I used clion. This is the cmake:               cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(copy_file C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(copy_file main.c)

Comment: @yano yes both run on the same machine, vm is not used

Comment: @IanAbbott done, both paths point to the same files

Comment: @GandhiGandhi yes , dual boot on the same ssd

Comment: Dual boot?  How is the ssd cross mounted under linux? What/where is the linux root FS? What environment is the windows code built under (e.g. mingw, cygwin, etc)? Did you try native win32 APIs?

Comment: Aside -- you know you can just use preporcessor conditionals to continually include code for Linux or windows, right? E.g. `#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)` (include the windows code here)  `#elif defined (__linux__) || define (__unix__)` (include Linux code here) `#endif`. Prevents juggling two files.

Comment: How many times have you run the tests? Do you delete the output file between tests? What sort of deviation are you seeing in the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great demonstration of how it's not the code we write that runs, it's the executable that the compiler makes from the code that runs.

It is possible that your Windows C compiler is not as advanced as your Linux C compiler, and is not optimizing your code as well as it could, or it's possible that the libraries that the Windows compiler is linking to for `fread()` and `fwrite()` are slower than the equivalent libraries in the Linux system.

If I had to put up my best guess, the Linux C compiler probably noticed that it would be more efficient to read more than one byte at a time, and it could do that without affecting the semantics of your program, and the Windows compiler either didn't infer the same, or wasn't able to optimize in the same way due to some underlying proprietary filesystem thing that only Microsoft engineers understand.

I can't say for sure without a peek at the disassembled binaries

Comment: Linux, by default, has a read buffer of `BUFSIZ` bytes (8192). There is little difference reading a character at a time or block of characters at a time. [glibc/libio/stdio.h - #define BUFSIZ 8192](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/stdio.h;h=b63ee88a776aa12586f086ab49d05baadd12aeed;hb=refs/heads/master#l99)

Answer (score -1):

One of the strengths of Unix/Linux is that files are designed to be treated as streams of bytes, with it being maximally easy and efficient to seek to the n'th byte using `fseek` or `lseek`.

Non-Unix operating systems, such as Windows, tend to have to work much harder to implement those seek operations.  In the worst case, they may actually need to read through the file, counting characters as they go.

Your code opens both files in binary mode, and this should reduce the need for the `fseek` implementation to perform any expensive emulations.  In text mode, a 10x performance penalty for heavy `fseek` use wouldn't surprise me.  I'm much more surprised you're seeing it in binary mode.

[Disclaimer: strictly speaking, in text mode `fseek` is *not* defined as seeking to an arbitrary byte offset at all, but rather, only to a position defined by the number returned by a previous call to `ftell`.  If an implementation takes advantage of that freedom, it can reduce the performance penalty for text-mode `fseek` operations, also, but it then means that code like yours, that constructs positions to seek to on the assumption that they're pure byte offsets, may not work at all.]

Comment: "In particular, they may need to literally read through the file, counting characters as they go." Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Well, (a) I've written the code myself, to emulate `fseek` on nun-Unix platforms.  And (b) I think I remember hearing that Windows may play games with `fseek` and text files to try to finesse the `\n` vs. `\r\n` difference for the benefit of Unix code that's making assumptions about how `fseek` works on Unix systems.  But, no, I don't have a source to cite.

Comment: Why would Windows play these games when the files are explicitly opened in `b`inary mode? Does this mean that Windows as a platform is fundamentally unsuitable for processing binary files?

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks.  I didn't notice the 'b' mode.  Answer updated.